# Using an array of struct counting the number of occurrence of a word in a text file C++

Tags: c++, avl-tree, word-count

Hi everyone this is my first time in Stackoverflow. I have a question regarding counting the occurrence of words in text file using C++. This is my code so far. I have to create an array struct of index of the word and the counter of each word then store all of them in an AVL tree. After opening the file and read a word, I look for it in the avl tree or trie. If it is there, use the node's index to increment the word's Cnt. If it is not there, add it to the word array and put its position in the next struct and put the structs position in the avl tree. Also I set the struct Cnt to 1. The problem I am having now is it seems like my program doesn't process the counting properly therefore it only prints out 0. Please give me recommendation on how I can fix the bug. Please find my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node* insert(struct Node* node, int key) ;
void preOrder(struct Node *root) ;
void removePunct(char str[]);
int compareWord(char word1[], char word2[] );

struct Stats {
    int wordPos, wordCnt;
};
Stats record[50000];
int indexRec = 0;
char word[50000*10] ;
int indexWord = 0;

int main() {
    ifstream fin;
    string fname;
    char line[200], wordArray[500000];

    cout << "Enter the text file name:" << endl;
    cin >> fname;
    fin.open(fname.c_str());
    if (!fin) {
        cerr << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    while (!fin.eof() && fin >> line) { //use getline
        for(int n=0,m=0; m!=strlen(line); m+=n) {
            sscanf(&line[m],"%s%n",word,&n);
            removePunct(word);
            //strcpy(&wordArray[indexWord],word);
            int flag = compareWord(wordArray, word);
            if(flag==-1) {
                strcpy(&wordArray[indexWord],word);
                record[indexRec].wordPos = indexWord;
                record[indexRec].wordCnt = 1;
                root = insert(root, record[indexRec].wordPos);
                indexWord+=strlen(word)+1;
                // indexes of the word array
                indexRec++;
                cout << wordArray[indexWord] << " ";
            } else
                record[flag].wordCnt++;

            cout << record[indexRec].wordCnt;
            cout << endl;

        }
        /*for(int x = 0; x <= i; x++)
        {
            cout << record[x].wordPos << record[x].wordCnt << endl;
        }*/

    }

    fin.close();
    return 0;

}

void removePunct(char str[]) {
    char *p;
    int bad = 0;
    int cur = 0;
    while (str[cur] != '\0') {
        if (bad < cur && !ispunct(str[cur]) && !isspace(str[cur])) {
            str[bad] = str[cur];
        }
        if (ispunct(str[cur]) || isspace(str[cur])) {
            cur++;
        } else {
            cur++;
            bad++;
        }
    }
    str[bad] = '\0';
    for (p= str; *p!= '\0'; ++p) {
        *p= tolower(*p);
    }
    return;
}
int compareWord(char word1[], char word2[] ) {
    int x = strcmp(word1, word2);
    if (x == 0 ) return x++;
    if (x != 0) return -1;
}

struct Node {
    int key;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    int height;
};

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b);

// A utility function to get height of the tree
int height(struct Node *N) {
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return N->height;
}

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b)? a : b;
}

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the given key and
    NULL left and right pointers. */
struct Node* newNode(int key) {
    struct Node* node = (struct Node*)
                        malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->key   = key;
    node->left   = NULL;
    node->right  = NULL;
    node->height = 1;  // new node is initially added at leaf
    return(node);
}

// A utility function to right rotate subtree rooted with y
// See the diagram given above.
struct Node *rightRotate(struct Node *y) {
    struct Node *x = y->left;
    struct Node *T2 = x->right;

    // Perform rotation
    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    // Update heights
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right))+1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right))+1;

    // Return new root
    return x;
}

// A utility function to left rotate subtree rooted with x
// See the diagram given above.
struct Node *leftRotate(struct Node *x) {
    struct Node *y = x->right;
    struct Node *T2 = y->left;

    // Perform rotation
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    //  Update heights
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right))+1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right))+1;

    // Return new root
    return y;
}

// Get Balance factor of node N
int getBalance(struct Node *N) {
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right);
}

// Recursive function to insert key in subtree rooted
// with node and returns new root of subtree.
struct Node* insert(struct Node* node, int key) {
    /* 1.  Perform the normal BST insertion */
    if (node == NULL)
        return(newNode(key));

    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    else // Equal keys are not allowed in BST
        return node;

    /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
    node->height = 1 + max(height(node->left),
                           height(node->right));

    /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor
          node to check whether this node became
          unbalanced */
    int balance = getBalance(node);

    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then
    // there are 4 cases

    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key)
        return rightRotate(node);

    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key)
        return leftRotate(node);

    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key) {
        node->left =  leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }

    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key) {
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}
void preOrder(struct Node *root) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->key);
        preOrder(root->left);
        preOrder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not simply use a `std::map<std::string, int>` ?

Comment: Looks like you're learning C and not C++.   Functions such as `removePunct` can be written with just 2 lines of C++ code.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://www.ideone.com/nNtPD2)

Comment: @Frank  I know it would be heaps easier if I could use STL but the requirements forbid me to do so

Comment: @ThangDau -- We do not know what these "requirements" are -- maybe you should post them so that persons attempting to answer don't waste their time posting C++ code using `std::map` and other things (such as using `std::remove_if`).

Answer (score 0):

One problem (I cannot see if this is the only problem) is that you have code like this, deleting all the intermediate lines:

```
record[indexRec].wordCnt = 1;
if find word fails
    indexRec++;
cout << record[indexRec].wordCnt;
```

So when you have a new word (if I understand the code correctly!) you are printing out the next record. One fix would be:

```
if (flag==-1)
    cout << record[indexRec-1].wordCnt;
else
    cout << record[indexRec].wordCnt;
```

There's a lot of other issues, like `compareWord()` is *very* wrong, you should decide if you really want to use C++ or just C with `std::cout`, the file reading code is odd, you're including both C and C++ versions of standard headers, etc, but these are issues for another question!